# Salesforce Dreamforce 2014 sessions recording

Tags: dreamforce

Can anyone please provide recording of useful dreamforce technical sessions. I know recording for Marc Benioff and some other management sessions are available. But Can anyone provide link for dreamforce technical sessions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Dreamforce '14 sessions are available [here](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF14/sessions.jsp#?search=blank&role=blank&product=blank&industry=blank&theme=blank). Specifically, you can filter on [Developer and Architect sessions](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF14/sessions.jsp#?search=blank&role=Developer-Architect&product=blank&industry=blank&theme=blank). Some great sessions I attended include:

- [Advanced Apex Enterprise Patterns](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/7QtP2628KmtXfmiwI-7B1w) (by our very own [Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett))
- [Apex Flex Queue: Batch Apex Liberated](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/TlKAT7avRO7UIeL0GvCUcw)
- [Building Salesforce1 Mobile Apps with Angular and Node](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/mY_sKru4E0YfzAzm-H0wzw) (one of my favorites)

I want to watch a bunch more, like [Faster SOQL? Yes, Please](http://dreamforce.vidyard.com/watch/4MfH1Hne0EV76ChTjSWfbQ).

Comment: This link has died & redirects to registration. I can still get at recordings for years I attended w/ https://success.salesforce.com/Ev_MyAgenda?eventId=[insert an ID here] but wasn't at 2014. Does anyone who was have a direct link to the video of a session referred to at https://github.com/Xtremefaith/Pardot-API-Example where the author claims to have heard that "managed packages" are good for credentials storage?  He doesn't specify which, but perhaps someone was there...  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

All session videos can be found [here](http://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/DF14/sessions.jsp).

[image]