# When will missing DF14 sessions be available online?

Tags: dreamforce

I know this only somewhat fits into a technical forum like this, but as many people from Salesforce.com read questions here and this question is of general interest...

**When will the videos of Dreamforce '14 sessions be online available that have no video link yet.**

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Salesforce Dreamforce 2014 sessions recording](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54222/salesforce-dreamforce-2014-sessions-recording)

Comment: Last time I checked, many technical sessions didn't have slides posted either.